# Website looks fine, but login to wp-admin yields a blank screen

Tags: wp-admin, login

I'm starting work on a client website and if you go to the site itself, everything looks fine. http://www.donoliverhomeimprovement.com
However, when I try to log into the wp-admin, I get a completely blank screen.
Any thoughts?

Comment: This is called the 'white screen of death' - searching for that may give you better results. You need another way to access the site such as ftp or ssh, and the first thing to try is disabling all the plugins so you can see if it's one of them causing the problem. This should be done carefully and will quite probably cause errors on the site, but may help you diagnose the issue. Does that help any?

Comment: It does. As it's a new client, working gingerly is always best, especially since the front end of the site appears fine. I've had the issue where a plugin blows up, but that generally affects the front end as well as the back end...

Comment: Yeah it's quite possible it's a plugin with code that only runs in admin, but hard to say. Also helps a lot if you can get the web server / WP error log - if you get the right log you'll be able to see the PHP error

Comment: As you shared the URL of your site, I went to /wp-admin and tried to login, because what else would I do on a Sunday night, and I found pretty interestingly the screen to tell me the login failed was blank but it was there and just hidden by CSS being set! the style .tt-body-login on line 24 in main-front-style.css sets opacity to 0 hiding the whole form!

Comment: It's really odd. Never run into something like this before. And as you can see, I'm on here Sunday night trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is causing the issue, I will advice you enable the error display in the wp-config.

Add the following line to the wp-config.php file:
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Or if it does exist, change the `false` to `true` and save the file.

Refresh your admin page and you will see the error which will help navigate to the root of the white screen.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have some other issues, but you have some CSS hiding your whole login form, which seems to get activated only if login fails.

```
.tt-body-login {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

On line 24 in main-front-style.css hides your whole login form, but it seems only in the case where the form has been submitted but it's redisplayed if e.g. password/username is wrong